# What do "reel out" and "pulled" mean in these lyrics?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

In the song "I hate you,i love you" by Gnash, there are some lines

> If I pulled a you on you, you wouldn't like that s___
>   I put this reel out, but you wouldn't bite that s___

What's the meaning of "reel out" and "pulled"? Can someone please explain to me?
Thank you!

Comment: For "reel out," think fishing. For "pulled a you on you," it means "if I pulled [the same trick you pulled on me] on you...." For "pulled a trick," see http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+a+trick.

Answer (score 3):

1. From M-W,

   > [pull](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull)
   >   to act or behave in the manner of <*pulled a Horace Greely and went west — Steve Rushin*>

   To *pull a you* here means to behave or act like *you*. So in essence, the first part means *if I were to act like you, you wouldn't like that*.
2. According to Google Play Music, the lyrics are [*I put this real out*](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tsxaeecybb3earpguh5tw6tjnoq?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics). However, *I put this reel out* is also a possible interpretation. *Reels* are used when fishing (fishing reels), and when the fish aren't taking the bait, you say "the fish aren't biting". In other words, *I put this reel out, but you wouldn't bite that s__* is a fishing metaphor. However, it's somewhat inaccurate. When fishing, you cast a (fishing) line, not the reel, with bait for the fish to bite. But we can just say that was due to "creative freedom". Anyway, one interpretation of the metaphor is that she tried to attract him, but he did not accept her.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that because this is from a song (about love) we should try so seek for a slang meaning for the words (search for sexual context).

1. [**Put out**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-out) ([Idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+out)) has one of those meanings *(to agree to have sex, provide sex)*.
2. [**Reel**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reeling) one of the meaning is: a reeling motion.
3. **[To reel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reel)** above all else means *to behave in a violent disorderly manner*.
4. [**To bite**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bite) - be persuaded to accept a deal or offer.

So theoretically that could mean that **"She agreed to try different things in sex with him but he wouldn't accept the offer"**

4. **[To pull a](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pull%20a%20)** - to behave the same way you do, to act like you do, to do something in the same way you do it.

   - *If I pulled a you on you, you wouldn't like that...* means *If I did what you did, you wouldn't like that...*

Comment: I don't think "put out" has a sexual connotation in this case.  Note that the lyrics say "Put this reel out", not "put out".  To put *something else* out isn't how the sexual idiom is used.

Comment: @stangdon Are you sure that the person who wrote the lyrics knows about it? But I guess you may be right.